# Finite dimensional representation of infinite group cannot be unitary: example with $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider the representation of the group of real numbers $\mathbb R$ given by
$$ \rho (x) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
for $x \in \mathbb R$.
How can we see that this representation cannot be equivalent to a unitary representation?

Comment: Certainly there are finite-dimensional unitary representations of infinite groups in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every unitary matrix is diagonalizable, but $\rho(x)$ is not diagonalizable unless $x=0$ (its only eigenvector (up to scaling) is $(1,0)$).